# How to save the values of one model in another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have `user model` and `Language model` where the language model contains different languages and i want the user to select the languages from that model and it should be stored for the corresponding user. Consider there are five languages `A, B, C, D, E` then the user has to select from the languages. Suppose `user 1` selects `A and C` whereas `user 2` selects `B and D` then the languages has to be stored for that user.  How can i do this? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to model a [many-to-many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) relationship. As explained in the link, this can be done by declaring

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

and creating a new table called something like `language_users` to store `user_id` and `language_id`. Each record in this table indicates that a particular user has selected a particular language.

Comment: Ok this stores the user has so and so languages and each languages has these users but instead can we be able to store the language values as  arrays in user model itself?

Comment: It would only make sense to do that if you limited the number of languages any single user can choose.

Comment: Probably there would be 20 languages at most. So can i able to do it?

Comment: The brute force (horrible) way to do it would be to have 20 separate columns. You obviously shouldn't do that. The next best option would be to have an array-type column, which is not possible in SQL, but _is_ possible with mongodb, because data is represented in a completely different way that allows this (it doesn't have columns). With SQL, you could work around this by storing a bunch of indexes in a single column as a string or encoded in an integer, but this would make queries inefficient, because you'd have to do some processing to extract indexes.

Comment: I think you have two options: (1) use the standard way as described above (this really is how something like this would be done in SQL), or (2) try mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through association,in your case you can try like:

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

`has_and_belongs_to_many :languages`

`end`

and

`class Language < ActiveRecord::Base`

`has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

`end`

or may be you can go through with the following links.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-models.htm

Comment: Ok this stores the user has so and so languages and each languages has these users but instead can we be able to store the language values as arrays in user model itself?

Comment: Sorry. I mean the languages. What i am trying is, i have iphone app where there is a text field languages where user should select multiple languages from the list and it should be stored.

Comment: @ragupathi it would be good if you do the same using association otherwise you will have to define as many field in your model as the number of languages you select and in the same situation as cdesrosiers has mentioned.

Comment: why cant we store the values as array in single field itself? why do we need as many fields as there are languages?

Comment: Which database are you using?i mean as far as SQL is concerned you can not have column of array type and i am using Neo4j data base and its also does not have property of array type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20215/discussion-between-heena-hussain-and-ragupathi)